# No "Code" received in FacebookApiException in PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, exception

When calling the /page_id/tabs api, with an out of bounds tab position, a FacebookApiExpection is thrown. The problem is that the code returned is '0', and the type is 'OAuthException'.

The question is, how can I handle this exception, distinguishing it from different possible exceptions thrown in the same call?

The `getResponse()` from the exception is as following:

```
Array
(
   [error] => Array
       (
           [message] => (#100) Position 2 is out of bounds
           [type] => OAuthException
       )

)
```